# How to add line borders to multiple outer and inner divs not overlapping

Tags: html, css

I got different `divs` nested:

```
<div id="outer">

    <div id="parametros"></div>

    <div id="resultados">

        <div id="graficos">
                <div id="bars"></div>
                <div id="fx"></div>
                <div id="pinchetabla">Tabla inútil</div>
        </div>

        <div id="loquerealmenteimporta"></div>  
    </div>

</div>
```

I added the following `CSS`:

```
#outer{

  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 1350px; 
  height: 640px;
  outline : 1px solid black;

}

#parametros {
  float:left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  outline : 1px solid black;

}

#resultados {
  float:right;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  outline : 1px solid black;
}

      #graficos {
        height: 75%;
        width: 100%;
        outline : 1px solid black;
      }

          #bars {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            width: 30%;
            outline : 1px solid black;
          }

          #fx {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            width: 30%;
            outline : 1px solid black;
          }          

          #pinchetabla {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            width: 40%;
            outline : 1px solid black;
          }

      #loquerealmenteimporta {
        height: 25%;
        width: 100%;
      }
```

In order to get all elements separated, I added a border line, but then the [result is not exactly what I expected](http://jsfiddle.net/8X9Xk/). I understand each `div` got its own border line of a certain thick so this happens.

What property offers the expected result?

Comment: All you say is this is not desired. Can you explain what *would* you like?

Comment: Borders at every `div` but any *thicker border* result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px;` to draw inside borders of your elements, this way it overlaps.

It is useful for test to see where elements are standing without disturbing margins, and size. http://jsfiddle.net/8X9Xk/1/

```
#loquerealmenteimporta {
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow:0 0;
}
div {
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px;
}
```

Comment: What do the three 0's mean? So the two ones in box-shadow? And, In that case last `CSS` *statement* means it'll be applied to every div?

Comment: yes, this is a fiddle :), but notice , the selector `#loquerealmenteimporta` is stronger and do not draw anything . You can add this shadow through a class and even tune it . so `box-shadow: 0 1px 0 ` ; will draw only one border .

Comment: Hmm I didn't understand you :P

Comment: Haven't, to be honest.Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with css3 box shadow

```
.box {
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #e9e9e9, 0 0 0 0 #e9e9e9, 1px 1px 0 0 #e9e9e9, 1px 0 0 0 #e9e9e9 inset, 0 1px 0 0 #e9e9e9 inset;
 }
```